# openpyxl save workbook to file with path

Tags: python, openpyxl

I use `Openpyxl` in Python to write some data in an Excel file using Workbook.
When I want to save the workbook to a file, I can only provide a filename argument, so I can not write files in other directories.

here is my sample code:

```py
import openpyxl

file_name = "sample.xlsx"

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

# writing some data to workbook

wb.save(filename=file_name)
```

I have checked the documentation via [this link](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html?highlight=save#openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook.save) and found nothing more.

Python: 3.10.7

Openpyxl: 3.0.10

Can you help me provide workarounds to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can indicate a full path + filename, and it will create a file where you need it:

`wb = Workbook()`

`wb.save(r'D:\folder\folder\folder\Filename.xlsx')`